# Mysql High UPDATE SELECT causing lag

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a game that is fairly sizeable, 30-40-50 people in at most points during the day. We store the information about their tank into a mysql database and when they shoot or lose health we dump that to the database. We are seeing a very high processor and HDD Spike because of this and the result is lag in the game.

Offending statements:

```
UPDATE MapData
SET Health = @1, X = @2, Y = @3,TotalPoints = @4
   , RankPoints = @5
WHERE MapID = @6
   AND TankID = @7
   AND Color = @8
```

I want to know if there are some things i can do to help with the lag at all.

```
CREATE TABLE `mapdata` (
  `MapID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TankID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Color` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `X` int(11) DEFAULT ''-1'',
  `Y` int(11) DEFAULT ''-1'',
  `Rank` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `Health` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''1000'',
  `Armors` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `Duals` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `Missiles` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `Homings` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `Radars` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `Beacons` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `HasRankKill` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b''0'',
  `TotalPP` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `RankPP` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `KillCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `DeathCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `TimePlayed` time NOT NULL DEFAULT ''00:00:00'',
  `EnabledEquipment` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `Prestige` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  PRIMARY KEY (`MapID`,`TankID`,`Color`),
  KEY `MapID` (`MapID`),
  KEY `TankID` (`TankID`),
  KEY `idx_mapdata` (`MapID`,`Color`,`TankID`),
  CONSTRAINT `mapdata_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MapID`) REFERENCES `maps` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `mapdata_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`TankID`) REFERENCES `tank` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Is there someway that I can persist the table in memory instead of on hdd and have it dump every so often back to disk?

Comment: What's the output of [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html)ing the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are things you can do but you have reached one of the hard thresholds to pass. The one where you have a write heavy system and it just doesn't write fast enough.

There are some ways of improve performance

1. Calculate god value for [innodb_log_file_size](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/)
2. Set [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) to 0 or 2. Note that 1 (default) is the only ACID compliant value but changing it to 0 or 2 gives much better performance.

There are more way of course, but these two are important.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check is if your configuration is optimized for InnoDB. Default MySQL settings are usually (depending on exact version but still) not optimized for InnoDB but more suited for MyISAM engine.

Percona's site has a nice introduction to: **[Innodb Performance Optimization Basics](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/)**

Number 5 on that list (setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2`) is exactly what Andreas proposed. There are many more options to examine.

---

About your question, you could use the **[Memory engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html)**. When your application starts, it would copy the table from disk to an identical memory table and use that afterwards for all operations, perodically updating the disk table. Or it could load only the data it needs every time (active in game player's data)

---

Alternatively you could add some (delay) mechanism in your application that does not send every update as a separate transaction but in batches.

---

Another thing you may consider is vertical partitioning the table. If you have some columns that are updated rarely and some that are very frequently updated, you could split the table into two parts. The updates would then done in tables with smaller width.

---

You have 4 indexes but some are redundant:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`MapID`,`TankID`,`Color`),
  KEY `MapID` (`MapID`),
  KEY `TankID` (`TankID`),
  KEY `idx_mapdata` (`MapID`,`Color`,`TankID`),
```

The `KEY MapID (MapID)` is not needed at all as the (1st part of the) Primary Key can be used instead.

The `KEY idx_mapdata` can be reduced to `(MapID, Color)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to scale up a lot more than where you are now then you will obviously need to look into software changes that will facilitate that, but if you'd like a quick performance increase at virtually no cost in development time then you might consider switching to a solid state drive if you're not using one already.

Have you considered reading/writing to ram memory instead of the database for active players, and then just persisting that memory to the database once they are no longer active?  That's gonna take some development time, but would definitely fix your problem.

Comment: We actually had a memory cache system but both have their negatives and positives. I can always revert back to that system but i was hoping mysql could handle it. I've made some of the adjustments stated and it seems to be running smoothly!

Comment: Actually, I wanted to add something similar as the most appealing scenario, if you have a real-time game server with a lot of players. It doesn't make much sense to store every change (of the game status) in the db, unless you have to be 100% safe in case of a system crash. In the extreme, you could even have your (game) application server store at the db, only at the beginning and end of a game (and "pause" status, if that is an option so the game can continue later).