# should I use memcached mysql or NO-SQL Database?

Tags: mysql, nosql

I'm working on a tcp server application that need dispatch around 1000 frames per second on java. Each ingoing frame generates an update (save state) and insert(for logging) to mysql. It says, 1000 updates and 1000 inserts per second!. I have a bottleneck in this updates and inserts. At this point, I don't know if mysql is a bad solution for my scenary because I'm doing the benchmarks on a PC, not on a server. I try execute Updates and Inserts in batchs periodically, but each batch takes a lot of time. 
I'm using MyIsam engine and Mina to manipulates tcp connection and a pool for the mysql connections.

Should I use memcached over Mysql or NO-SQL, or it can be a hardware resource problem?

thanks!
regards!!

Comment: Ok... I try to set InnoDB engine, with one commit per batch and tunning InnoDB like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281791/mysql-high-update-select-causing-lag... I get very good results =D, but not enought.

Comment: Have you thought about putting something in between the database and your application to buffer the writes? Thinking out loud, but might try a queue? Then you can throttle the writes a bit.

Comment: Yes, I use a two queues. One to updates and other to inserts, with two timers. When a timer is trigger, it launch a batch with all queries of queue and empty it, but it taked so much time. At this moment, this works with the solution of my last comment, but I think that I will have a scalability problem at future, I wonder if I should use memcached or NO-SQL engine.

Comment: There is no such thing as NoSQL. There is just a whole bunch of database technologies with completely different philosophies and uses-cases, and all they have in common is that they somehow store data. Asking "will NoSQL solve my data problem" is like asking "will NoRoad solve my transportation problem".

Comment: thanks for the free information! 
http://nosql-database.org